# How to return value from a promise that's inside another function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I know that a lot of questions have been asked about async programming and Promises, but I really need an example with this specific code to figure out how I should go about returning promises that's being returned in another function.

I have two functions. The first one is called upon GET'ing to a route. This route should create a payment link and save a booking to a database.

```
exports.create_booking = function(req, res) {

      req.body.payment = exports.create_booking_payment(req.body.total_amount);

      console.log(req.body.payment); // This returns ' Promise { <pending> } '

      var new_booking = new Booking(req.body);
      new_booking.save(function(err, booking) {
        if (err)
          res.send(err);
        res.json(booking);
      });

};
```

However creating the payment link happens with an asynchronous method. My first problem was that I could only access the payment inside the methods callback function.

Now I have wrapped the method inside another (async) method in which a Promise is created and resolved. This method is being returned to my first method with an await statement, but all this returns is: ' Promise {  } '.

I know that this happens because the method is being returned before the promise is resolved. But I don't understand why this is. My assumption is that the 'await' statement makes sure to wait returning the method before the async function is completed.

```
exports.create_booking_payment = async function() {

function asyncPayment() {
  return new Promise (function(resolve, reject) {

      mollie.payments.create({
          amount:      20.00,
          description: "Reservation code: ",
          redirectUrl: "https://www.website.com/",
          webhookUrl:  ""
        }, function(payment) {
              if (payment.error) reject(payment.error)
              else { resolve({
                  id: payment.id,
                  link: payment.getPaymentUrl(),
                  status: payment.status
                })
              }
      });

   });
 }

 return await asyncPayment();

}
```

I hope someone can help me out here...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You seem to have missed that an `async` function still returns a promise, not the actual value.  So, when you call `create_booking_payment()`, you are getting back a promise that you need to use either `.then()` with or `await` with.  There's no free lunch across a function boundary.  `await` allows you to program in a synchronous-like fashion inside a function, but still does not allow you to return the value from the function.  When it looks like you're returning the value from the `async` function, you're actually returning a promise that resolves to that value.

So, you'd do this with `async` and `await`:

```
exports.create_booking = async function(req, res) {

   try{
      req.body.payment = await exports.create_booking_payment(req.body.total_amount);

      console.log(req.body.payment);

      var new_booking = new Booking(req.body);
      new_booking.save(function(err, booking) {
        if (err)
          res.status(500).send(err);
        else 
          res.json(booking);
      });
   } catch(e) {
      res.status(500).send(err);
   } 
};
```

or this with `.then()`:

```
exports.create_booking = function(req, res) {

      exports.create_booking_payment(req.body.total_amount).then(payment => {    
          console.log(payment);
          req.body.payment = payment;
          var new_booking = new Booking(req.body);
          new_booking.save(function(err, booking) {
            if (err)
              res.status(500).send(err);
            else 
              res.json(booking);
         });
    }).catch(err => {
        res.status(500).send(err);
    });

};
```

Note, I also added more complete error handling to both scenarios.  Also, this code would be a lot cleaner if you "promisfied" or used an already promisified interface for your `.save()` method.  I strongly dislike using plain callback async code inside of promise-based code because it ends up duplicating error handling (like you see in this case).

---

Also, `create_booking_payment()` doesn't need to be `async` or use `await` since all you need it to do is to return your promise which it already knows how to do:

```
exports.create_booking_payment = function() {

  return new Promise (function(resolve, reject) {

      mollie.payments.create({
          amount:      20.00,
          description: "Reservation code: ",
          redirectUrl: "https://www.website.com/",
          webhookUrl:  ""
        }, function(payment) {
              if (payment.error) reject(payment.error)
              else { resolve({
                  id: payment.id,
                  link: payment.getPaymentUrl(),
                  status: payment.status
                })
              }
      });

   });

}
```

Comment: and with this, the function `exports.create_booking_payment` function doesn't need to have `async` and the return doesn't need to `await`, because it's returning a promise

Comment: @Kaddath - Yes, that's true, I added that.